# How to open and plot Globcolour chlorophyll image in R?

Tags: r, netcdf

Level 3 globcolour chlorophyll images (download from hermes) are in netCDF format. Those files can be imported via ncdf package to R 3.1.

```
ch.nc = open.ncdf("E:/Data/globclour/L3b_20140101-20140131__GLOB_4_AV-MOD_CHL1_MO_00.nc")
```

How can I plot CHL1_mean? I follow [guide by Mark](http://menugget.blogspot.com/2012/04/working-with-globcolour-data.html) but not getting any success.

Comment: Well how about a link to a file or some idea of what you've tried already?

Comment: Working with L3 bins is relatively difficult if you don't understand it. You should study the materials and forums posts on it here http://oceancolor.gsfc.nasa.gov/, explore the blog posts you are quoting more, and ask more specific questions on aspects you have problems with. I have been working with the oceandata L3 bin files, but this is also the first time I've seen these data in NetCDF-that-could-be-opened-in-R, so that's interesting to me (thanks).

Comment: thanks for reply.I tried to use oceancolor L3 products which in HDF4 format. those images also hard to import to R directly. Any suggestions to import global chlorophyll monthly data?

Comment: Following the guide gives good results for me. What problem do you encounter?

Comment: The 25 and 100km versions are easily readable in R using the `raster` package.

Comment: @Pascal, 4km data stored in ISIN grid and 25km and 100km data stored in simple PC grid which is easy to plot.

Comment: @sudheera You don't answer the question. Why are you getting any success following the link you provide? Which error?

Comment: @ pascal, Your answer is correct! it will give excellent plot for 25km data. i just edit your path to download ne_10m_admin_0_countries_lakes and readOGR path for shape file which stored elsewhere than working directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example with the 25-km dataset, for January 2014, followed by an example for the 4-km dataset, January 2014 (improvement are welcome). The 4-km version is read using the example given [here](http://menugget.blogspot.com/2012/04/working-with-globcolour-data.html). You need to download functions from the same website: [val2col](http://menugget.blogspot.com/2011/09/converting-values-to-color-levels.html), [image.scale](http://menugget.blogspot.com/2011/08/adding-scale-to-image-plot.html) and [earth.dist](http://menugget.blogspot.com/2011/05/r-functions-for-earth-geographic_29.html).

```
# Required librairies
library(rasterVis)
library(rgdal)
library(grid)

# Land mask using Natual Earth data (http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-physical-vectors/)
msk <- readOGR(".", "ne_10m_admin_0_countries_lakes")

# 25 km
CHL1 <- raster('L3m_20140101-20140131__GLOB_25_AV-MOD_CHL1_MO_00.nc', varname='CHL1_mean')
names(CHL1) <- 'CHL1_mean'

# Get values from the RasterLayer
z <- getValues(CHL1)

# Create breaks
brks <- c(0,0.01,0.02,0.03,0.05,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.5,1,2,3,5,10,20,30,50,100)

# Substitute chlorophyll values to classes
new_z <- findInterval(z, brks)

# Write new values in RasterLayer
CHL1 <- setValues(CHL1, new_z)

# Create color palette
pal <- rev(colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(11, 'Spectral'))(100))

# Customize legend
ckey <- list(at=seq_along(brks),
             labels=list(at=seq_along(brks),
                         labels=brks,
                         cex=1))
 # Plot chlorophyll
Obj <- 
  levelplot(CHL1, margin=FALSE, col.regions=pal, at=seq_along(brks), colorkey=ckey) +
  layer(sp.polygons(msk, fill='grey', col='transparent'))

print(Obj)
trellis.focus("legend", side="right", clipp.off=TRUE, highlight=FALSE)
grid.text(expression(paste("[",mg/m^3,"]",sep="")),1,0.50,rot=90)
trellis.unfocus()
```

[image]

Another approach for the 4-km version, adapted from [here](http://menugget.blogspot.com/2012/04/working-with-globcolour-data.html). This example is plotting chlorophyll around Florida.

```
# Required libraries
library(ncdf4)
library(classInt)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)
library(raster)

# Create "extent" object for cropping, here focus on Florida
e <- extent(-85,-80,20,30)

# Land mask using Natual Earth data (http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-physical-vectors/)
msk <- readOGR(".", "ne_10m_admin_0_countries_lakes")
CP <- as(e, "SpatialPolygons")
proj4string(CP) <- CRS(proj4string(msk))
ne_10m_land <- gIntersection(msk, CP, byid=TRUE)

# Open the NetCDF file
nc <- nc_open('L3b_20140101-20140131__GLOB_4_AV-MOD_CHL1_MO_00.nc')
idxrow <- ncvar_get(nc, "row")+1
idxcol <- ncvar_get(nc, "col")+1
val <- ncvar_get(nc, "CHL1_mean")
nc_close(nc)

# From http://menugget.blogspot.com/2012/04/working-with-globcolour-data.html
Re <- 6378.145
Nlat <- 4320

dr <- (pi*Re)/Nlat
dPHI <- pi/Nlat

PHI <- -(pi/2)+(1:Nlat)*dPHI-(dPHI/2)

p <- 2*pi*Re*cos(PHI)
Nlon <- round(p/dr, 0)
dlon <- p/Nlon
dphi <- (2*pi)/Nlon
Ntot <- sum(Nlon)
lat <- PHI*180/pi

g.row <- idxrow
g.col <- idxcol
g.lat  <-  lat[g.row]
Nlon_row <- Nlon[g.row]
g.lon <- (360*(g.col-0.5)/Nlon_row) - 180

Nlon_row <- Nlon[g.row]
g.width <- 360/Nlon_row
g.height <- 180/Nlat


# Crating SpatialPointsDataFrame
CHL1 <- data.frame(x=g.lon, y=g.lat, g.width=g.width, g.height=g.height, z=val)
coordinates(CHL1) <- ~x+y
proj4string(CHL1) <- CRS('+init=epsg:4326')

# Cropping the SpatialPointsDataFrame to the area of interest
CHL1 <- crop(CHL1, e)

# Get values from the SpatialPointsDataFrame 
z <- CHL1$z

# Create breaks
brks <- c(0,0.01,0.02,0.03,0.05,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.5,1,2,3,5,10,20,30,50,100)

# Substitute chlorophyll values to classes
new_z <- findInterval(z, brks, rightmost.closed = TRUE)

# Write new values in RasterLayer
CHL1$z <- new_z

# Creating polygons
out <- split(cbind(coordinates(CHL1), CHL1$g.width, CHL1$g.height, 1:length(CHL1)), 1:length(CHL1))
foo <- function(x){
  xx <- c(x[1]-x[3]/2, x[1]-x[3]/2, x[1]+x[3]/2, x[1]+x[3]/2, x[1]-x[3]/2)
  yy <- c(x[2]-x[4]/2, x[2]+x[4]/2, x[2]+x[4]/2, x[2]-x[4]/2, x[2]-x[4]/2)

  Sr <- Polygon(cbind(xx,yy))
  Srs <- Polygons(list(Sr), paste0('s',x[5]))
}
polys <- lapply(out, foo)
polys <- SpatialPolygons(polys, 1:length(polys))
projection(polys) <- CRS('+init=epsg:4326')

# Creating colors
source("val2col.R")
pal0 <- rev(colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(11, 'Spectral'))(100))
colcode <- val2col(new_z, col=pal0)

# Mapping
source("earth.dist.R")
source("image.scale.R")
XLIM <- c(e@xmin, e@xmax) 
YLIM <- c(e@ymin, e@ymax)
x.dist <- earth.dist(XLIM[1], mean(YLIM), XLIM[2], mean(YLIM))
y.dist <- earth.dist(mean(XLIM), YLIM[1], mean(XLIM), YLIM[2]) 
heights <- c(6)
widths <- c(heights[1]*x.dist/y.dist, 1.5)

par(omi=c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1), ps=12)
layout(matrix(c(1,2),nrow=1,ncol=2,byrow=TRUE), widths = widths, heights = heights, respect=TRUE)
layout.show(2)
par(mai=c(0.5, 0.5, 0.1, 0.1), las=1)
plot(CHL1$x, CHL1$y, t='n', xlim=XLIM, ylim=YLIM, xaxs="i", yaxs="i", xaxt="n", yaxt="n")
plot(polys, col=colcode, border='transparent', add=TRUE)
plot(ne_10m_land, border='transparent', col='grey', add=TRUE)
axis(1, seq(-85,-80,2), parse(text=degreeLabelsEW(seq(-85,-80,2))))
axis(2, seq(20,30,2), parse(text=degreeLabelsNS(seq(20,30,2))))
box(lwd=2)

par(mai=c(0.5, 0.1, 0.1, 1))
image.scale(new_z, col=pal0, horiz=FALSE, yaxt="n", ylab="", xlab="")
lab <- sort(unique(new_z))[2:(length(unique(new_z))-1)]
axis(4, lab, brks[lab])
mtext(expression(paste("[",mg%.%m^-3,"]", sep="")), side=4, line=3)
box()
```

[image]

Comment: Land mask shapefiles path (http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/)

Comment: Yes, it is written as a comment of the script.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion to open 4km data?

Comment: Yes, explain more explicitly why, following the link you provided, you have no success in plotting the 4-km version.

Comment: that script is written for batch processing as i understood. i download all files and make path as script. tmp = unlist(strsplit(shell(paste("dir", raw_path), intern=TRUE), " "))  this is not working for me. then i just tried to open single file and read chl data. i can not skip date field in data frame. therefore i couldn't go further. if u could simplify the steps for just single image, it will very helpful

Comment: I added an example for 1 single file.

Comment: @ pascal, second example solved my problem. it needs raster package for extent function.

Answer (score 0):

I have problem like this :

> source('G:/2016/WBS3/tes/teschl.r')
>   Loading required package: sp
>   rgdal: version: 1.1-10, (SVN revision 622)
>    Geospatial Data Abstraction Library extensions to R successfully loaded
>    Loaded GDAL runtime: GDAL 2.0.1, released 2015/09/15
>    Path to GDAL shared files: C:/Users/Acer/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/rgdal/gdal
>    Loaded PROJ.4 runtime: Rel. 4.9.2, 08 September 2015, [PJ_VERSION: 492]
>    Path to PROJ.4 shared files: C:/Users/Acer/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/rgdal/proj
>    Linking to sp version: 1.2-3 
>   rgeos version: 0.3-19, (SVN revision 524)
>    GEOS runtime version: 3.5.0-CAPI-1.9.0 r4084 
>    Linking to sp version: 1.2-3 
>    Polygon checking: TRUE

Error in ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding, use_iconv = use_iconv,  : 
  Cannot open data source

with code like this:

## Required libraries

library(ncdf4)
library(classInt)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)
library(raster)

## Create "extent" object for cropping, here focus on Florida

e <- extent(20,80,160,-20)

## Land mask using Natual Earth data (http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-physical-vectors/)

msk <- readOGR(".", "G:/2016/WBS3/idv/lakes/ne_10m_lakes")
CP <- as(e, "SpatialPolygons")
proj4string(CP) <- CRS(proj4string(msk))
ne_10m_land <- gIntersection(msk, CP, byid=TRUE)

## Open the NetCDF file

nc <- nc_open('G:/2016/WBS3/Datalama/CHL1/CHL1-1997-09.nc')
idxrow <- ncvar_get(nc, "row")+1
idxcol <- ncvar_get(nc, "col")+1
val <- ncvar_get(nc, "CHL1_mean")
nc_close(nc)

## From http://menugget.blogspot.com/2012/04/working-with-globcolour-data.html

Re <- 6378.145
Nlat <- 4320

dr <- (pi*Re)/Nlat
dPHI <- pi/Nlat

PHI <- -(pi/2)+(1:Nlat)*dPHI-(dPHI/2)

p <- 2*pi*Re*cos(PHI)
Nlon <- round(p/dr, 0)
dlon <- p/Nlon
dphi <- (2*pi)/Nlon
Ntot <- sum(Nlon)
lat <- PHI*180/pi

g.row <- idxrow
g.col <- idxcol
g.lat  <-  lat[g.row]
Nlon_row <- Nlon[g.row]
g.lon <- (360*(g.col-0.5)/Nlon_row) - 180

Nlon_row <- Nlon[g.row]
g.width <- 360/Nlon_row
g.height <- 180/Nlat

## Crating SpatialPointsDataFrame

CHL1 <- data.frame(x=g.lon, y=g.lat, g.width=g.width, g.height=g.height, z=val)
coordinates(CHL1) <- ~x+y
proj4string(CHL1) <- CRS('+init=epsg:4326')

## Cropping the SpatialPointsDataFrame to the area of interest

CHL1 <- crop(CHL1, e)

## Get values from the SpatialPointsDataFrame

z <- CHL1$z

## Create breaks

brks <- c(0,0.01,0.02,0.03,0.05,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.5,1,2,3,5,10,20,30,50,100)

## Substitute chlorophyll values to classes

new_z <- findInterval(z, brks, rightmost.closed = TRUE)

## Write new values in RasterLayer

CHL1$z <- new_z

## Creating polygons

out <- split(cbind(coordinates(CHL1), CHL1$g.width, CHL1$g.height, 1:length(CHL1)), 1:length(CHL1))
foo <- function(x){
  xx <- c(x[1]-x[3]/2, x[1]-x[3]/2, x[1]+x[3]/2, x[1]+x[3]/2, x[1]-x[3]/2)
  yy <- c(x[2]-x[4]/2, x[2]+x[4]/2, x[2]+x[4]/2, x[2]-x[4]/2, x[2]-x[4]/2)

Sr <- Polygon(cbind(xx,yy))
  Srs <- Polygons(list(Sr), paste0('s',x[5]))
}
polys <- lapply(out, foo)
polys <- SpatialPolygons(polys, 1:length(polys))
projection(polys) <- CRS('+init=epsg:4326')

## Creating colors

source("val2col.R")
pal0 <- rev(colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(11, 'Spectral'))(100))
colcode <- val2col(new_z, col=pal0)

## Mapping

source("earth.dist.R")
source("image.scale.R")
XLIM <- c(e@xmin, e@xmax) 
YLIM <- c(e@ymin, e@ymax)
x.dist <- earth.dist(XLIM[1], mean(YLIM), XLIM[2], mean(YLIM))
y.dist <- earth.dist(mean(XLIM), YLIM[1], mean(XLIM), YLIM[2]) 
heights <- c(6)
widths <- c(heights[1]*x.dist/y.dist, 1.5)

par(omi=c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1), ps=12)
layout(matrix(c(1,2),nrow=1,ncol=2,byrow=TRUE), widths = widths, heights = heights, respect=TRUE)
layout.show(2)
par(mai=c(0.5, 0.5, 0.1, 0.1), las=1)
plot(CHL1$x, CHL1$y, t='n', xlim=XLIM, ylim=YLIM, xaxs="i", yaxs="i", xaxt="n", yaxt="n")
plot(polys, col=colcode, border='transparent', add=TRUE)
plot(ne_10m_land, border='transparent', col='grey', add=TRUE)
axis(1, seq(-85,-80,2), parse(text=degreeLabelsEW(seq(-85,-80,2))))
axis(2, seq(20,30,2), parse(text=degreeLabelsNS(seq(20,30,2))))
box(lwd=2)

par(mai=c(0.5, 0.1, 0.1, 1))
image.scale(new_z, col=pal0, horiz=FALSE, yaxt="n", ylab="", xlab="")
lab <- sort(unique(new_z))[2:(length(unique(new_z))-1)]
axis(4, lab, brks[lab])
mtext(expression(paste("[",mg%.%m^-3,"]", sep="")), side=4, line=3)
box()

Comment: This does not answer the question. If you have a new question, please ask it.